# Magento2.4.4 pagebuilder having issue When we change content and save

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4, page-builder

Magento2.4.4 pagebuilder having issue When we change content and save

[image]

Comment: Did you check application and server logs?

Comment: yes,but there is a same kind of information Showing